# This simple method make memory usage increase constantly

Tags: c#, linq, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

This code makes constant increase of memory usage until `OutOfMemoryException` are thrown. I tried to force the GC, but it didn't help, The `ClusterResultDBDataContext` is a Linq to Sql class.
To me everything looks fine, can someone spot some problem?

```
    static void getDistinct()
    {
        var db = new ClusterResultDBDataContext();
        var result = new LinkedList<Tuple<int,int>>();
        using(var sw = new StreamWriter("result.txt"))
        {
            foreach(var y in db.Results)
            {
                var cnarr = y.PaperResults
                    .OrderBy(x => x.DOI).Select(x => x.ClusterNumber).ToArray();
                var re = cnarr.Aggregate((x, a) => (x * 10 + a) % 19930727);

                Console.WriteLine(y.ID+" " +re);
                sw.WriteLine(y.ID + ","+re);
                GC.Collect();


                //result.AddLast(new Tuple<int, int>(y.ID, re));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to flush the writer sometime during the processing the collection of your results.

Comment: @MaximFleitling i dont think that the streamwriter would use so much memory to make a outofmemoryexception...

Comment: Do you Dispose your context?

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you may close the connection to db after executing your task and query and also you should not call db.Results in each iteration.

Try this:

```
static void getDistinct()
    {
        using (ClusterResultDBDataContext db = new ClusterResultDBDataContext())
        {
            var result = new LinkedList<Tuple<int, int>>();
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("result.txt"))
            {
                var results = db.Results;
                foreach (var y in results)
                {
                    var cnarr = y.PaperResults
                    .OrderBy(x => x.DOI)
                    .Select(x => x.ClusterNumber).ToArray();
                    var re = cnarr.Aggregate((x, a) => (x * 10 + a) % 19930727);

                    Console.WriteLine(y.ID + " " + re);
                    sw.WriteLine(y.ID + "," + re);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A good answer should contain more than just "try this" and a block of code. Explain what you've changed. Explain *why* you've changed it. Explain why you believe it fixes the OPs problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Added some info... :-)

Comment: i splitted the `Results` table, and for each table an individual datacontext object is used, and it works. Also, the diagnostic analysis in visual studio showed that there are reference cycles in the DefferedSource object with PaperResult object